# Dependency 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, modelmapper

I am using springBoot 2.7.7 with maven and when I paste ModelMapper dependency in my pom.xml, it shows error saying: Dependency 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:' not found

[attached a error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTBna.png)

Comment: did you run mvn clean install after adding dependency?

Comment: thank you for the info, I will keep this in mind next time i post questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run mvn clean install; then if the problem persists i'd suggest you look into you maven folder for a ***settings.xml*** file.

It's usually located on %USERPROFILE%/.m2

[image: settings.xml file location example]

If you have a file like that, maven may look for dependencies on other repositories addresses instead of the default one.

So just delete or rename it. run maven again and restore the file back.